Power supply 8pin + 6pin graphics with limited cables
I actually have a RX 570 sapphire nitro+ 8gb graphics card
And I have a power of 530 watts.
The female graphics pin is one 8 and one 6.
My free power cables are one 2+6 and one 4-pin and 2 molex
What is the best solution to fill 14 graphics pins with this power?

“What is the best solution to fill 14 graphics pins with this power?” - Get an adapter cable for the PCIe power cable. Moped isn’t helpful with modern current generation GPUs. Or simply upgrade your PSU.
